# Ansible how to construct array from shell registered output including respective hostname

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am trying to get the status of a process from each host of a specific group and print the hostname and process status in table format.

```
[nginx]
172.1.0.1
172.1.0.2


---
hosts: all
tasks:
  - name: Get process status
    shell: ps -ef| grep [n]ginx
    register: nginx_status
    when: '"nginx" in group_names'
```

Expecting array/table format like as below(I'm using shell command return code here to define UP or DOWN).

Ex:

```
jinja2 template to capture output:

{% for output in nginx_status.stdout_lines %}
{{ output.hostname }}  {{ if output.rc == 0 UP else DOWN }}
{% endfor %}
```

The template is not mandatory, Final output is all that I am expecting.

```
Final output:
HOST      NGINX
172.1.0.1 UP
172.1.0.2 DOWN
```

In the end, consolidated output from each group should be like.

```
HOST      NGINX Some-x Some-Y
172.1.0.1 UP     DOWN  UP
172.1.0.2 DOWN   UP    NA(Not Applicable)
```

Comment: See [service facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html). And don't use complex when clause: loop on the hosts in group at play level directly (i.e. `hosts: nginx`)

Comment: I have 10 groups and I need to check separate process status in each group. To write 10 playbooks for each group seems not a good practice.

Comment: Then put 10 plays in the playbook -- one for each group.

Comment: Sure, I will try once I figure main logic. And service facts are not usable for me as I'm not using systemd.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to get the output printed to the console, then try filtering the output of running a playbook. There are ways to do this purely in ansible, but it gets more involved with using `map`.

`test.yml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: nginx
  tasks:
    - name: Get process status
      command: pgrep nginx
      register: proc_status
      changed_when: false
      failed_when: false

    - debug:
        msg: "###HOST           NGINX###"
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "###{{ ansible_host }} {{ (proc_status.rc == 0) | ternary('UP', 'DOWN') }}###"
```

Running: `ansible-playbook test.yml | grep "###" | cut -d'#' -f4`
should result in something like:

```
HOST           NGINX
192.168.15.101 UP
192.168.15.102 DOWN
```

Your use case may vary with the `###` tokens and table column layout (using Linux `column` command?), but this should provide the basics for solving the problem.

Note that your original `ps -ef | grep ...` does not filter itself from the results so will always give a match. You'd need to adjust with something like `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep [n]ginx` if you take that route over `pgrep`.

Comment: Goal is not to print in the console. I have multiple groups and different services in each group. The goal is to get each host and respective service status in a file so I cant print it as output later.

Comment: Simply I cant use grep and other filters to ansible command as there are other tasks that I need to output in the console.

Comment: In that case, you can either rework this same solution into a template, or more simply, just replace the `debug` tasks with `shell` tasks that create and append the same `msg` contents to a local file (using [delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) - have the first one create the file `>`, and the second append to it `>>`)

Comment: If I use delegation with ```localhost``` to append in the same file then ```{{ ansible_host }}``` will become localhost instead of each host IP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering because I don't have enough rep to comment.

"If I use delegation with localhost to append in the same file then {{ ansible_host }} will become localhost instead of each host IP. – SNR"

"{{ inventory_hostname }}" will still be what it says on the tin, even on "delegate_to: localhost" tasks.